# d3js dynamically accessor children

Tags: json, d3.js

I am creating with the **d3 tree layout** a tree. My data is as already as a tree but not with the d3js format ( `{name: "", "childrend": []}` ) but with a simple JSON tree format like :

```
[{
    "A": [{
        "AA": []
    }, {
        "AB": []
    }, {
        "B": [{
            "BA": []
        }, {
            "BB": []
        }]
    }]
}]
```

Of course, the data is not with `"A"` and `"B"`, is just for making the JSON more clear and give just a part of my data. (My data not following a pattern as the exemple)

I saw i could use `tree.children()` to change the name, but how can i dynamically do it ?!

I need to use this tree format with d3 tree layout.

Answer (score -1):

So since you can write an accessor function, you can make it smarter than just returning a single property.

The function can be made to check each object key and return it if the corresponding value contains children.